# Plastic Man peeping on Wonder Woman?

Tags: dc, episode-identification, wonder-woman

I read that Plastic Man  once sneaked into Wonder Woman's room and watched her undress and from that point on the two don't work together often. Can someone tell me the name of the comic book/series?

Comment: So, Wonder Woman had *Plastic* Man \*cough\* in her bedroom? That doesn't seem like a story you'd see in a normal comic book and nothing too special to even have as a plot. :)

Comment: He at least once got caught masquerading as a dress Big Barda had put on. The final shot on *that* page involved Barda trying to strangle him, but the next scene had him still on the JL team for some reason...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [JLA vol 1. #62](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/JLA_Vol_1_62). (Golden Perfect, Part I).
Plastic Man disguises himself as a light fixture but gets called on it.

[image]

> **Wonder Woman:** *Just wondering... If my body was the **last** thing you saw, **ever**, would it be worth it?*"

Comment: until the **next** time... I think this implies that this wasn't the first time Plastic Man was peeping on her. Especially because she immediately knew he was there without lashing out at him. Like it has happened before and she knew getting angry at him wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: The question I have in that scene is actually why Martian Manhunter didn't say anything, because his powers make it so that he must have known.

Comment: @Durakken wasn't that sort-of addressed some years ago because Plasticman's brain has been plasticized and is therefore no longer organic and doesn't work the same way as everybody else's? Also, as a chemist, declaring plastic to be inorganic sets my teeth on edge.  But that was some JLA series with an invasion and Plas had retired to raise his son and Martian Manhunter had to drag him out of retirement because he was the only one on earth capable of stopping the menace (what about all the other elemental heroes like the MetalMen?)

Comment: @Broklynite dunno. My knowledge of those characters are limited. It might be the case. And yeah I get what you mean by calling plastic inorganic, but then dividing chemistry into organic and inorganic is a bit stupid to begin with so it's forgiven imo.

Comment: @Broklynite: Plastic Man isn't literally made out of plastic. That part of his name refers to the fact that he can reshape himself. Initially, the creators wanted to call him India Rubber Man. But yes, his structure has fairly consistently rendered him immune to telepathy. Batman referred to it as that his mind is "no longer organic", but it's probably closer to indicate that it's no longer human, as seen in Rock of Ages where he's shattered into millions of pieces that are scattered for thousands of years, then he's perfectly fine once they're gathered together.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm aware that in this case Plastic is used as an adjective rather than a noun, that was meant to be a joke. However, that said, unless he has become some sort of living mineral or ceramic or whatever, he likely is organic. I know, I know, it's a comic book... And Durakken anyone who has taken both organic and inorganic chemistry courses will laugh their heads off at the idea that there's no reason to separate the two disciplines.

Comment: I suppose that really is the question, whether he still is made of organic material. The writing kind of wavers on it with characters commenting that he's "not organic" (including Batman, who was the one who pointed out that his brain is not organic and that it makes him immune to telepathy, specifically Martian telepathy in that story arc) and yet a 2007 miniseries had Eclipso and Dr. Sivana extract DNA from him, and he's sired a son who has the same powers as him.

Inconsistent writing, probably.

Comment: Great Pink Panther reference there, Plastic Man!